# Render only 3 columns with display grid

Tags: css, sass

I need to only display 3 columns and everything else needs to be hidden. I'm assuming that I need to change the height of the container dynamically so that it's only the height needed to contain 3 columns, but I dont know how to do that and I also dont know if it's the correct method.
Any help would be appreciated

I'm using scss but I dont care if you give me a example in css

```
.contentContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 5px;
  place-items: center;

  height: 330px; // I'm assuming this needs to change dinamically

  overflow: hidden;
  
  .imageContainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      aspect-ratio: 1/1;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:
I dont have a problem if I need to use JavaScript

Comment: Which 3 columns ? First ones, last ones, specific ones ?

Comment: I only want to display the first 3 columns

Answer (score 0):

XY-Problem!

It is not an issue based on the grid itself. If you want to hide all elements with the exception of the first 3, you have to use the `:not(:nth-child(-n+3))` selector to hide all elements within the grid with the exception of those first 3:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.container > div:not(:nth-child(-n+3)) {
  display: none;
}


/* for visualization purpose only */
.container > div {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  min-height: 30vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: or `.container > div:nth-child(n+4)`